# Bit manipulation (iterate through all subsets)

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, bitmask

I don't understand why below doesn't work.

I've tried everything I can do - but no progress.

```
int b = 0;
int x = (1<<1)|(1<<2)|(1<<3)
do {
    // process subset
} while((b=(b-x)&x));
```

What I wonder is that expression `b=(b-x)&x`
 iterate all subsets.

I searched google like 'bit manipulation' or 'bit subset iterate' but there's no answer or hints.

Please help me.

Even Stackoverflow don't have this question. at all..

Answer (score 0):

this question is horribly asked, I would recommend you to rewrite and clarify what exactly are you asking

meanwhile when doing bit-wise operations you must be familiar with binary representation and specifically to this case two's-compliment representation of negative numbers

x is initialized as `b'1110` and in decimal representation `14`
so let's examine the first iteration `b = (b - x) & x`

first, since `b=0` and `x=14` then `(b-x) = -14` or in two's compliment `...111110010`

second, with the `x` masking the result will be (consider just the 4 LSBs) `0010 & 1110` so the result after the first iteration: `b=b'0010=d'2`

you can try and run this code with prints to understand the iteration process - it usually makes things more understandable:

```
int counter = 0;
int b = 0;
int x = (1<<1)|(1<<2)|(1<<3);
printf("init x: %x\n", x);
do {
    printf("iteration:%d subset:%x\n",counter++, b);
    printf(" intermediate(b-x): %x\n", (b-x));
} while((b=(b-x)&x));
```

With all that said... WHAT IS THE QUESTION?